# Не понимаю как реализовать поворот блока при наведении и его открытие на весь экран, затем - сворачивание

Tags: javascript, css

https://youtu.be/7pr0x3elUzQ
Буду признательна если поможетеПри наведении на блок он поворачивается под углом, при клике на блок - открывается сам блок на весь экран (плавно), при клике на лого - сворачивается открывшийся блок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: css-анамацией, но тут жесть...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для поворота есть **css** правило `transform` и его аргумент `rotate(deg)` для плавного перехода между состояниями - есть **css** правило `transition`, при клике переключаем класс `active`, в котором обратный поворот на 0 и размер на весь экран

Все это вместе дает вот что:

```js
let el = document.querySelector('div');
el.onclick = function() {
    el.classList.add('active')
}

document.querySelector('span').onclick = function() {
    el.classList.remove('active');
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

div {
  font-size: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 300ms;
  background-color: wheat;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

div:hover {
  transform: rotate(11deg);
  color: red;
}

div.active, div:hover.active {
  font-size: 200px;
  line-height:200px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  color: red;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 30px;
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 300ms;
}

span:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>❤</div>
<span>☁</span>
```

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь!!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const logo = document.querySelector('.logo');
const rotate = document.querySelector('.rotate');

rotate.addEventListener('click', () => rotate.classList.add('active'));
logo.addEventListener('click', () => rotate.classList.remove('active'));
```

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rotate{
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 70px;
  top: 50px;
  transition: all 400ms;
}

.rotate:hover{
  transform: rotate(12deg);
}

.rotate.active{
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">logo</div>
<div class="rotate"></div>
```

Comment: Вадим, спасибо Вам огромное!